# how to wait in shell script until a module is loaded?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that should load a kernel module at first.

```
modprobe wlcore_spi
```

The next step should wait this process to be finished(an output on std "wlcore loaded") then move forward. But how can this waiting action be done? I tried:

```
modprobe wlcore_spi
wait
echo "hello world"
```

It seems it's not worked as I expected.
I searched abt it and it seems the best should be find the pid then simply wait for it. 
Then I start this job then typed "ps aux", it seems it's not in the process? It seems it starts somehow another process and eventually gives back a signal when it's finished. How can I catch this?

Comment: When modprobe exits it finished.

Comment: @IporSircer Hi. I updated more details.

Comment: modprobe is a process that terminates after having done the job. So you should have nothing to do, as Ipor Sircer said. But, if you want, you can parse the output of modprobe, or its standard error, or the output of lsmod(8), or the output of "cat /proc/modules".

Comment: @linuxfan I got it. I can write a loop to check if the module is already loaded or not? Many thnx.

Comment: May be, but you can simply use modprobe and rely on that: if the module is already loaded, nothing happens; otherwise modprobe loads it. Very easy, sincerely I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @linuxfan ah. the problem is this process takes very long, might up to 1 min. For the following process I have to wait for this module be successfully loaded.

Comment: May be a cycle monitoring the output of lsmod? Or a small utility that calls that module to see if it is initialized and working (in case it results loaded, but not fully operational).

Comment: @linuxfan Hi. I tried with lsmod, it failed, cause even the module is loaded. The ifconfig -a still shows nothing. So I wrote a loop with ifconfig -a | grep wlan0. And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use && option for your case.

```
modprobe wlcore_spi && echo "hello world"
```

So command B will be executed when commanded A exited successfully.